# Show Dock icon, but no standard Main Menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsapplication

Is it possible to have a Dock icon for the application, but no main menu in the menu bar?

- Fiddling around with `LSUIElement` and `LSUIBackgroundOnly` doesn't lead to my goal.
- Setting `[NSApp setMainMenu:nil]` didn't work.

**EDIT**: To be more concrete: I do not want to hide the menu bar, but hide the app's main menu, that is, the menu of the application before activating my app, remains visible.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think that is possible. Normally people would go for a menubar app (right side), and skip the dock/having a menu (left side)

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking of implementing an app with a behavior similar to apps like LaunchPad or Mission Control: you can activate them and they do not show any kind of menu.